# Is it possible to visually distinguish certain rows in the iris data set in a PCA?

Tags: r

I wonder if it is possible to distinguish for example the three first rows in the virginica dataset from the rest. I'm thinking it could be done by giving them a different shape. Any ideas?

```
iris
plot = function (data) {
  data = data %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(Species = iris$Species)
  cols = as.list(setNames(colnames(data), c('x', 'y', 'color')))
  ggplot(data, do.call(aes_string, cols)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed()
}

petal_data = select(iris, Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
pca <- prcomp(petal_data)
rotated_petals <- as.data.frame(pca$x)
plot(rotated_petals)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can create another column to distingush these 3 rows and feed into `shape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could add an `id` dummy which is `1` for the rows to identify, else `0`. In the plot use `id` as value for `pch` parameter.

```
iris2 <- transform(iris, Species=as.character(Species), id=0)
iris2[1:3, "id"] <- 1

petal_data <- iris2[c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")]
rotated_petals <- data.frame(prcomp(petal_data)$x, Species=iris2$Species, id=iris2$id, 
                             stringsAsFactors=F)

u.spec <- unique(rotated_petals$Species)
col. <- 1:length(u.spec)
incr.pch <- 1

plot(rotated_petals[-(3:4)], type="n")
sapply(seq(u.spec), function(x) 
  with(rotated_petals[rotated_petals$Species == u.spec[x], ],
       points(PC1, PC2, col=col.[x] + 1, pch=id + incr.pch)))
legend("topleft", legend=c(u.spec, "identified"), col=c(col., "grey50"), 
       pch=c(1, 1, 1, 1 + incr.pch), horiz=T, bty="n", cex=.9)
```

### Result

[image]

**Note,** that you attempt to override the base R `plot` function which is a bad idea. Use `rm(plot)` to reset before running this solution.